# MapView CLLocationManager always giving new location for the same place

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager didUpdateLocations to get current location of device.
Its provide me the current location but after in few seconds I am getting different latitude and longitude for the same place with no movement in device.
I want to implement 5 metre distance check in my app, but due to frequently change in location provided by delegate method I always getting the more than 5 meter difference between old and new location.

Can anybody suggest what is the best way to find out accurate distance.

Comment: Dear.. In delegate method after getting location stop fetching location like [CLLocationManager stopUpdating];

Comment: Agree Sir but I want to capture location while user is moving so that I can notify user if user cross 5 metre from their previous location.
So once I get the distance I can not stop it because I would required it again.

Comment: Unfortunately the GPS is not calibrated down to 5 meters. I have read somewhere that the best accuracy is 100 meters. But it certainly isnt 5.

Comment: 5 meter accuracy is not desirable for iOS current and the accuracy is vary according to the place that device located in, sometimes it can be 30~40 meters and sometimes it can be over 100 meters